# Atom Terminal: Windows PowerShell not opening

Tags: powershell, atom-editor, platformio

I have installed Atom and the platformio-atom-ide-terminal package.But the terminal screen is blank and I not getting "Windows powershell prompt" or directory path.I am running a simple Python code.

- Python Version: Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- Atom version:1.34.0

I tried changing the setting.

```
Map Terminal:File.Working directory:Active file.PFB
```

Screenshots:

[image: Blank Terminal]

[image: Settings]